# Control the number of decimal digits in custom ticks

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

Let's define a custom colorbar

```
Clear["Global`*"];

colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"C", None}, {None, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Thick, RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, ticks[min, max]}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20, Plain],
ColorFunction -> colorFunction];
```

where

```
ticks[min_, max_] := Module[{positions = Range[min, max, (max - min)/5], 
precision = Length[NestWhileList[10 # &, max/5, Floor@# != # &]] - 1,labels},
If[precision > 0, 
labels = ToString /@ (NumberForm[#, {Infinity, precision}] & /@ positions)];
If[precision == 0, labels = ToString /@ Floor[positions]];
Transpose[{positions, labels}]]

valrange = {0.134512, 10.623245};
Show[colorbar[valrange, "Rainbow"]]
```

I want the following:

How can we modify the module `ticks`, so as to be able to control the number of printing decimal digits? For example the limits in `valrange` have six decimal digits, however we may want only 2.

I use version 9.0.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Why the following approach do not work?

```
ticks2[min_, max_, dd_] := Module[{ran = Range[min, max, (max - min)/5]},
NumberForm[ran, {dd + 1, dd}]]

Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, dd_, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"C", None}, {None, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Thick, RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, ticks2[min, max, dd]}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20, Plain],
ColorFunction -> colorFunction];

valrange = {0.123, 10.232};
Show[colorbar[valrange, 3, "DeepSeaColors"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using as much as you originally had, this works:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

colorbar[{min_, max_, prec_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] :=
   DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"C", None}, {None, None}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Thick, RotateLabel -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, ticks[min, max, prec]}, {None, None}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20, Plain],
    ColorFunction -> colorFunction];

ticks[min_, max_, prec_] := 
 Module[{positions = Range[min, max, (max - min)/5], 
   precision = 
    Length[NestWhileList[10 # &, max/5, Floor@# != # &]] - 1, labels},
   If[precision > 0, 
   labels = 
    ToString /@ (NumberForm[#, {Infinity, prec}] & /@ positions)];
  If[precision == 0, labels = ToString /@ Floor[positions]];
  Transpose[{positions, labels}]]

valrange = {0.134512, 10.623245, 3};
Show[colorbar[valrange, "Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

WL Version 11.2 has new function: [DecimalForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DecimalForm.html). It allows enforcing of decimal form and control of total and after-decimal-point numbers of digits.

Control total number of digits:

```
DecimalForm[N@Pi, 5]
```

> 3.1416

Reduce number of digits after-decimal-point

```
DecimalForm[N@Pi, {5, 3}]
```

> 3.142

...or increase

```
DecimalForm[N@Pi, {5, 7}]
```

> 3.1416000

Answer (score 1):

Why not minimize the digits shown by using the default ticks function? For example:

```
colorbar[{min_,max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := DensityPlot[
    y,
    {x, 0, 0.1},
    {y, min, max},
    AspectRatio->10,
    PlotRangePadding->0,
    PlotPoints->{2,divs},
    MaxRecursion->0,
    Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{{"C",None},{None,None}},
    FrameStyle->Thick,
    RotateLabel->False,
    LabelStyle->Directive[FontFamily->"Helvetica",20],
    FrameTicks->{{None,Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"]},{None,None}},
    FrameTicksStyle->Directive[FontFamily->"Helvetica",20,Plain],
    ColorFunction->colorFunction
];
```

Then:

```
valrange={0.134512,10.623245};

Show[colorbar[valrange,"Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I want the specific ticks module, for printing always 6 ticks.